# Port blocking on client machines

Tags: networking, internet, group-policy, ports

Is it possible to block specific ports, in this case 80 and 443 for specific client machines. I am using windows server 2012 as a domain controller and have a group of clients that I want to be denied access to the internet but to be allowed on local intranet. Using the server I want to set this up so the group have those ports blocked. Many thanks

Comment: You can use the Windows firewall to do this right?

Comment: If you block those ports, then it both Intranet and Internet traffic on those ports will be blocked, you want to take a different approach to accomplish your goals.